# How index and manage doucuments based on a frequently changed grouping topology?

Tags: elasticsearch

Consider a customer as the searchable entity. This customer belongs to a unit. So I added the `unitId` to the `customer` type. A unit can belong to one or more groups, and groups can have parent groups.

For instance:

- `unit1` belongs to `texas` group child of `usa` group child of `north-america` group
- `unit1` also belongs to `eletronic-stores` group child of `home-appliances` group
- `unit1` also belongs to `mall-stores` group
- ...

I would like to search customers based on the unit group. However, the grouping topology changes very often to fit the management needs. In this case, I figured out 2 options:

- add `groupIds` to the document and reindex all customers affected when topology changes and populate the correct `groupIds` in each one.

  - Search is faster but changes to the topology is way more expensive.
  - Reindex affects search response.
- Deal with the unit grouping outside the index and search by a set of UnitIds.

  - The search will always must have 2 steps: get unitIds for a group, and search document.
  - The query can get very large: `"filter" : "terms" : { "unitId" : [1, 2, 3... 99999 ] }`

Both of them do not seem to be a good choice. So, How can I index and manage documents based on a frequently changed grouping topology like this with ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch doesn't really like frequently changing data. Every time you update a document it effectively marks the old document stale and creates a new one then every once in a while runs some defragmentation routines.

If your use case can not tolerate search results being stale for a while, you'll have to use the second path. We have been running ES queries with tens of thousands of parameters; performance was not great but not terrible either.

If you can afford some delay in indexing, I would probably try to benchmark both ways and try to figure out how big those trade offs are. Maybe you can filter only docs related to changed units, and it won't be a huge amount and you can reindex it every night or every hour or every 10 minutes?